# Labels not rendering properly with OSM Bright style on Openlayers using Tileserver

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, vector-tiles, tile-server, osm2vectortiles

Referring the document at [Tilerserver](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/website/openlayers/) I am using my local tileserver-gl-light but my label are not rendered correctly. Label appears as {name:latin}{name:nonlatin} or {name:en}{name:nonlatin} refer the screenshot

[image: Label appears as {name:latin}{name:nonlatin} or {name:en}{name:nonlatin}]

This happens only when I change the style to http://localhost:7070/styles/osm-bright/style.json whereas If using the default https://openmaptiles.github.io/klokantech-basic-gl-style/style-cdn-undecorated.json it works fine.

Am using ol v4.3.1 and olms.js v2.6

Comment: If you don't get an answer here try asking at https://help.openstreetmap.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that 'text' parameter to the `fromTemplate` function in olms.js is passed with 2 objects `{name:latin}{name:nonlatin}` and the `match()` function fails to find it. I modified the my olms.js file to and now I am able to see labels of point entities, namely City, Town, Locality names

`function fromTemplate(text, properties) {
  // hardcoded to show only 'name_int' 
  text = "{name_int}";
  var parts = text.match(templateRegEx);
  if (parts) {
    var value = properties[parts[2]] || '';
    return parts[1] + value + parts[3];
  } else {
    return text;
  }
}`

but still I am unable to display labels on Road/Street. As suggested by @scai would post the query on https://help.openstreetmap.org/ to get a better solution which fixes for point, line and polygon labels.